# wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

The following command got the error. However, I can get the json result if I open  https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest in browser?

```
PS C:\> .\bin\docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Virtual Switch Main" default
```

> Running pre-create checks...
>
> (default) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
>
> Error with pre-create check: "Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest: read tcp 10.8.159.1:50158->192.30.253.117:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I tried the following and got the same error.

```
.\bin\docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Virtual Switch Main" --engine-env "HTTP_PROXY=http://myProxy.com" --engine-env "HTTPS_PROXY=http://myProxy.com" default
```